# Performance of assigning the same array/object element to the same element

Tags: javascript, performance, v8

I am curious about the performance of assigning the same element to itself. Is V8 smart enough to understand this should not be executed?

```
obj.key = obj.key;
```

The use case would be something like.

```
Object.keys(otherObj).forEach(e => {
  if(!obj[e]) {
    obj[e] = foo();
  }
});
```

If we use a ternary operator instead of if-statement, would there be a penalty performance?

```
Object.keys(otherObj).forEach(e => obj[e] = obj[e] ? obj[e] : foo());
```

Comment: What was the result of your benchmark ?

Comment: `obj[e] = obj[e]` is different from `obj[e] = (… ? obj[e] : …)`. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: For what reason would you ever prefer that possibly-slow and totally unreadable construct over a simple `for (const e in otherObj) if (!obj[e]) obj[e] = foo();`?

Comment: Notice that is cannot be treated as a no-op when a getter/setter property is involved, so V8 would at least have to always check for that.

Comment: @Bergi I am curious what happens in both cases.

So `obj.key = obj.key` will be different in performance compared to `obj[e] = obj[e]`?

Comment: @IvoSabev No, not in the regard that both would be a no-op. (Of course a dynamic property assignment/lookup is always slower than a static one). Both should be optimised in the same way - which mostly depends on what `obj` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 developer here. I don't think there's a case where `obj[e] = obj[e]` assignments will be optimized away. Deciding that such an optimization would be valid requires so much knowledge about `obj` and `e` that checking for all that would in most cases be too expensive to be worth it.

As Bergi points out, `obj[e] = (... ? obj[e] : ...)` is conceptually significantly more complicated and therefore even less likely to ever be optimized away, even if you assume that we'll spend a couple more years improving V8.

Regarding `obj.key` vs `obj[e]` (for both loading and storing), if they both see only one object shape and only one property name, they'll have pretty much the same performance. If `[e]` sees more than one property name (like in your example looping over `Object.keys()`), it will be somewhat slower; however `.key` isn't really an alternative there -- it's precisely the flexibility of `[e]` that makes it slower. If either of them sees more than one shape for `obj`, they'll be slower than otherwise, with `[e]` taking a bigger hit than `.key`; this will e.g. be the case when your loop ends up adding properties that weren't there before.

All that said, any performance differences are probably too small to matter, and my recommendation is to write the code that's most readable -- or run your own measurements to figure out with certainty whether there's a measurable difference in your case. Keep in mind that microbenchmarks are often misleading; use an app that comes as close as possible to your production environment for such tests.